# Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (2 responses were required but only 1 replica responded)

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

One of our applications is occasionally getting the error:

```
Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (2 responses were required but only 1 replica responded)
```

In the course of an hour we might get 20 or 30 of these over 10,000 queries or more.  And a retry of the query generally works.

It does appear to be a timeout of some sort.  The error appears in the application logs, but I don't see any corresponding error or warning, or anything really, in the cassandra system.log nor debug.log.

All of the searches I'm doing online lead to queries where people see this consistently, but for me it's not consistent.  The cluster itself it healthy, and other queries return just fine.  The table being queried isn't large (a few tens of MB on each server).  Looking at tablehistorgrams, I'm not seeing anything overly large for reads or writes on any server for the table in question.  CPU, memory, etc, are all fine.

A typical histgram for that table is currently

```
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)
50%             2.00             29.52            152.32              1916                72
75%             3.00             35.43            379.02             24601               770
95%             3.00             51.01            379.02            454826             14237
98%             3.00             61.21            379.02            654949             20501
99%             3.00             73.46            379.02            785939             24601
Min             0.00             14.24            105.78               180                 6
Max             3.00             88.15            379.02           1629722             51012
```

Although I don't have one from immediately after this error appeared.

Running Apache Cassandra 3.11.3.  16 node cluster (8 nodes in each DC).  Replication is DC1:3, DC2:3 (for all tables in all user keyspaces).  Driver is configured to use DCAwareRoundRobin, and all reads and writes are LOCAL_QUORUM.  Application (like all of our applications) is write heave.  STDC configured, if that helps.

We see much less timeouts on writes, but they are not zero:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during SIMPLE write query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (2 replica were required but only 1 acknowledged the write)
```

If it matters, this is occurring with Akka persistence tables for this particular application.

I'm looking for possible suggestions as to cause, please, as I haven't been able to find anything (and I don't have much hair to pull out...).

Thanks.

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (2 responses were required but only 1 replica responded)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:91)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:66)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:297)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:268)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
... 34 common frames omitted
```

We have several applications using this cluster.  This isn't the only application with errors, but I figure by fixing this app it will fix the others.

Comment: Seems like replicas are too loaded to respond within configured time out..you may try out increasing the value in Cassandra.yaml

Comment: What is the query and table structure?

Comment: How long is your timeout? One thing you could check is Garbage collection. Do you use CMS or G1GC? Your logs will show if there are "stop the world" pauses happening. Or use some utility to check GC. If this is your problem, you could could change GC algorithm or configure it to avoid the timeouts. https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsTuneJVM.html

Comment: The timeout would be the default, so 2 seconds.  Using G1GC and Oracle JDKa 1.8u172.

Comment: I did find an issue where Cassandra was throwing a lot of these errors:  org.apache.cassandra.db.UnknownColumnFamilyException: Couldn't find table for cfId ...

The schema version was the same acorss the cluster.  A cluster restart didn't help, nor did a repair (the repair against the table failed), so we eventually dropped the table and had the app recreate it.  I had to restart the cluster again then to get the schema to match, but after that the issues for that app disappeared, as did the errors.

I need to validate if this has 'fixed' any other apps.